# how to extract a string from binary string in TensorFlow TFRecord

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tfrecord

I have a binary string, retrieved from part of a TFRecord in a sparse tensor that looks like when printed:

```
SparseTensor(indices=tf.Tensor(
[[0]
[1]], shape=(2, 1), dtype=int64), values=tf.Tensor([b'Jones' 
b'Felicity'], shape=(2,), dtype=string), dense_shape=tf.Tensor([2], 
shape=(1,), dtype=int64))
```

I'd like to get the 'Jones, Felicity' string out of that lot, does anyone know how to do this, please?
Thank you.

Comment: You can access the content of a SparseTensor through its `values` property. Is that what you're looking for? If not, please provide enough code to clarify your issue.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you Matthew.